# R optional subset in function

Tags: r, function, subset, option-type

I have a dataframe as follows

```
    individual  species   Pdays ... Gdays 
1   alpha       opuntia   4         9
2   alpha       physalis  4         10
3   beta        opuntia   3         9
4   beta        physalis  5         8
```

Where individual and species are categorical factors. I am attempting to write a function where I can look at effects of species, and OPTIONALLY by individual. I cannot figure out how to optionally subset individual. So far I have:

```
 seed_germination <- function (dataframe, species, individual) {
    mydata <- read.table(dataframe, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    attach(mydata)

 subset_mydata <- mydata[mydata$species == species, ] 

 subset_ind <- subset_mydata[subset_mydata$individual == individual, ]                   
    #ignored if individual not specified

    }

 test <- seed_germination(dataframe = 'test.csv', species = 'opuntia',                    
       individual = 'alpha')
```

I have played around with

```
  if(missing(individual))
      return()
```

with various things in return() to no avail.

Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Just provide a default value to individual like `function(df,species,individual=NULL)` and use an `if (individual==NULL) do_stuff` More generally, just find a tutorial. This is functions-in-R 101: https://www.google.com/#q=writing%20r%20functions

Comment: I agree with @Frank. If you want the function to also work with multiple species and individuals, then you could use `is.null(individual)` for checking the arguments, and `%in%` for the subsetting, instead.

Comment: @Jason Also try deleting `attach(mydata)`.